# Recent API information on opening a camera in Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

This might come off as a weird post, because I don't directly want answers to how to fix this just yet. Over the past few weeks now I've been searching for good tutorials/information on opening the camera in Android Studio Kotlin with a button and having it ask for permission and all that jazz and allow you to take a picture and save it to the app, not the camera roll (I want to use the picture in several places of the app, and having it in the camera roll is not needed and also just takes up space). As of now I've tried several YouTube tutorials, and tried a few different ways that have been posted over the years but it seems most don't work and are severely outdated. I don't know if I'm implementing them wrong, which is very possible, I'm not well versed in Android Studio, and have been trying to learn. However most of the times the button just ends up not working, sometimes it doesn't do anything, sometimes it ends up crashing depending on which tutorial I use to help, or whatnot. I'm mainly here asking if anyone has any updated sources that I can look towards and at this point I will take anything, API Pages, YouTube, another Forum, anything that can point me in the right direction for this is insanely appreciated, the only thing I don't want is direct answers because I do want to be able to learn from this experience and hopefully be able to move forward with it without having to use a tutorial every time in the future, and direct answers aren't really going to help me achieve that.

I've tried to use several different ways to open the android camera, ask permission, and take a picture. So far the farthest I've gotten is it crashing, but most often it just doesn't do anything when said button is pushed. I even went for a more direct approach originally, eliminating the button as a whole and using just the navigation bar, but that went about as well as anything else did. Over this time I've tried maybe half a dozen or more tutorials and/or posts on another sites and stack overflow, and not only are each a different way, they're either many years old or using deprecated ways to complete the objective, and none seem to work. From this I would greatly appreciate just a link to a more up to date spot to learn how to use the camera.

Comment: This kind of open ended question is off topic for this site. I recommend going on a message board or Discord for Android developers for this kind of discussion.

Comment: `I don't know if I'm implementing them wrong, which is very possible` All you want is possible and has been done by any one who started programming for Android. Nothing special what you want. Code is everywhere on the internet and on stackoverflow. This is no open end. The end is near. Do it step by step. But post the code you tried instead of talking and complaining